# Find External IP without website possible in Windows Vista?

Tags: windows, networking, windows-vista, command-line

Find my external ip address without a website - is it possible in Windows Vista?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should be in the router configuration. Your cable or DSL modem provides your router with its external IP.

Open up the command prompt (cmd) and type ipconfig. Copy the default gateway into the address bar of your web browser. Log into your router. On the router status page... there you should see the external IP address that has been assigned to your router.

Answer (score 3):

If you have access to your cable or DSL modem's web interface (usually through http://192.168.1.1 or 0.1), you can try looking there. My modem's interface has a Status tab, where it shows the WAN IP address.

Answer (score 1):

Try:

`ping -r 1 www.yahoo.com`

It will try to ping `www.yahoo.com` and show you the route for the first hop, which should be the IP address of your router.

Note that nothing is magical about `www.yahoo.com`. You could ping whoever your want.

**Update:**

You could also try `tracert -h 1 www.yahoo.com`, which will give you the IP address of your first hop out to the Internet (which should be your router).

Comment: Kindly notice the part where he said "without website".

Comment: Ah... I'm an idiot. I'll edit with a different thing to try.

Comment: That doesn't work for me. http://www.whatsmyip.org/ gives me 84.92.xxx.yyy (which is correct) while the ping gives me 84.92.mmm.nnn.

Comment: @OmNom Nom: Do you think an ftp, or dns server would do? They're not *technically* websites :P

Comment: @ChrisF That's interesting. I'm not sure why that is happening.

Comment: 1     1 ms     1 ms     1 ms  StaticWifi.local [192.168.9.1]
So yea that doesn't work lol

Comment: @MrStatic Maybe try -h 2 (will give you two hops)

Comment: @Chris Dwyer, nope 1 is wifi AP 2 some random comcast IP but not one of my 5 statics and 3 is a random comcast router out there.

Comment: @Chris,  Try it, it doesn't!  Yes, it gives first hop.. But it gives the IP of the interface at your end. That's the 192 address. The same thing that ipconfig shows.  He wants the external IP. Not sure if that's the IP of the interface on the other end of your router, or the IP of the interface you connect to at your ISP's router.. But external ip is external ip.. you can see yours and you'll see your method won't give it. Nice idea though! I thought you might've been onto something!

Answer (score 1):

there's a gadget in the online gadget gallery called network meter that will display your internal and external ip address.  There's also a bunch of windows utilities that will do the same.

Network Meter:
http://gallery.live.com/liveItemDetail.aspx?li=89fc6d27-0fe9-4c40-b1f4-e1c393415bff

utilities:
http://www.snapfiles.com/freeware/network/fwip.html